# Yocto helloword recipe in rootfs

Tags: yocto

I have created a new recipe is helloworld example in manual.
I'm using imx6sx processor, so created it in meta-freescale-3rdparty folder as recipes-helloword and checked this layer whether has been added to bblayer.conf. It can be compiled with bitbake helloworld there was no error and it exists in rpm folder. After that, the image compiled again with bitbake fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx and generated a new rootfs and sdcard file.

However, I can't find the application in rootfs. Where is the application in rootfs? (the recipe has been inserted in local.conf : IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " helloworld")

.

```
./recipes-helloworld/
└── helloworld
    ├── helloworld
    │   ├── COPYING
    │   └── helloworld.c
    └── helloworld_0.0.bb

2 directories, 3 files
```

helloworld_0.0.bb

```
SUMMARY = "Hello World Cpp App Sources"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PV = "1.5"

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S= "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Comment: if helloworld is installed, it is in `/usr/bin/helloworld`

Comment: Yes, it has been installed but there isn't there.

Comment: can you try `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p helloworld` ?

Comment: it gives /usr/bin/helloworld path

Comment: If you use rpm package-management, can you run `rpm -qa | grep helloworld` on target?

Comment: I can't run rpm command on imx.  What should we do? or is there another solution?

Comment: Maybe try to regenerate your image with `bitbake -c clean fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx && bitbake fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx`, then mount generated rootfs locally with `cd <deploy-dir>; mkdir test ; mount -o loop <img>.ext4 test; ls test/usr/bin/helloworld` ?

Comment: Yes, there is it in test/usr/bin/. However, after it has been generated, I have uploaded new image to sdcard and there isn't in /usr/bin/ again. Can the problem exist while uploading sdcard? I'm using this command to upload; sudo dd if=fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx-imx6sxsabresd.sdcard of=/dev/sdb bs=1M && sync

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the build manifest of the image to see if helloworld is in there:

```
{build_folder}/tmp/deploy/licenses/{image_name + last_timestamp}/package.manifest
```

If it's there you should find helloworld in `/usr/bin/helloworld`

If it's not, helloworld package is not being included in the image.

Comment: Yes, helloworld is in the manifest file but there isn't in /usr/bin folder.

Comment: Answering your last comment (I can't comment there because I don't have the reputation, I'm new here :/): To copy image to the SD card I always follow this procedure : 1- Unmount all the partitions (with `umount /dev/sdb?` ), 2- Copy with `dd`, 3- `sync`, and 4- Eject the SD (with `eject /dev/sdb` ). It could be this issue, I remember I have the same issue a year ago until I make a script with this 4 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check 'helloword' application is available in 'helloword' package. Means it is  built and put in /usr/bin. If it's available in image directory it means this binary is being installed into rootfs as part of the helloword package.

```
(build_dir)/tmp/work/***/hello word/***/image/usr/bin
```

If it is available it indicates the helloword package is being built and create the binary and it's installed in to /usr/bin and plan to put into rootfs.

Since you have already added the package in local.conf as IMAGE_INSTALL_append, it should built as part of target.

If it is not available still, can you please add the following line in recipe

FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/helloword"

Then try to rebuild 'helloword' and final traget and check the binary is available in rootfs.